# Getting the number of nested functions in PHP

Tags: php

How can I get the number of times a function has been nested in PHP?

Eg.

```
function infinite(){
  infinite();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recurse like this:

```
function infinite($depth = 1) {
  infinite($depth + 1);
}

infinite();
```

Then `$depth` contains the current level of recursion inside the function.

You could also fiddle with [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but this is not very efficient, so you should for example not execute that in every step of the recursion!

Comment: I would suggest supplying a default of `1` for `$depth`, so you could call it with no arguments: `function infinite($depth = 1) { ... }`

Comment: @meagar: That's absolutely correct. The reason why I didn't add this in the first place was that I wasn't sure whether PHP actually supported default arguments (and too lazy to look it up). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$depth = count(debug_backtrace());
```

This will tell you the length of the call stack.

Comment: But not necessarily the how many times that particular function has been called.

Comment: Juts filter the array for `function=>'infinite'` or whatever.